# Google BigQuery Failed Error Unexpected, Please try again

Tags: google-bigquery

This query

```
select word from [publicdata:samples.shakespeare] where word="aslp"
```

gives me an error

```
Query Failed
Error: Unexpected. Please try again.
```

Till today morning this thing was working fine and giving no error.But now when i try this its throwing error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug introduced this morning handling queries returning no results. It should be fixed in the next few minutes.